# How do I use a regex in perl like this (.+) for specified string?

Tags: regex, linux, perl, unix, testing

I am using this code:
    `m/MSG\[(.+)\]/`

to detect any character between square brackets and coloring it using this code:

```
if($currentLine=~m/MSG\[(.+)\]/){  
 $p1=$1;  
 $outp="$p1";  
 $currentLine=~s/MSG\[(.+)\]/MSG[$cg$outp$crs]/g;}
```

The above code colors to the end of the line and doesn`t detect the close square bracket. How can I get this to only color to the close square bracket?
for example, using this code, (.+) meaning:

```
((\?+\s+\?+)|(\?+\s+\d+)|(\w+\s+\?+)|(\w+\s+\w+)|(\d+)|(\w+)|(\?+)|(\d+\s+\w)|(\?+\d+)|(\?+\s)|(\d\?+))
```

are you understand the above code or explain for you?

Comment: What are `$cg` and `$crs`?

Comment: $cg & $crs is variable like $currentLine but use for color `$cg="\e[1;1;32m"; #fg green & $crs="\e[0m";`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$currentLine =~ s/MSG\[([^\]]+)\]/MSG[$cg$1$crs]/g;
```

Comment: @lehr88: In which it didn't work? Please, edit your question and add full examples with input strings and expected results.